# PowerShell .ps1 file on Visual Studio post build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, powershell-2.0, nuget, post-build-event

I am trying to execute the following post build event code but I am getting an non-useful error :

```
"c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"
```

I have run the following PS script before I try :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

This is strange, I am not getting an error on VS now. but the script is not working. When I run it with powershell console I get the following error :

[image]

Comment: non-useful error? Neigh-on impossible to answer without *some* clue as what problem you're getting.

Comment: Not able to answer this [but I found a useful link for you](http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reproduce the error in Powershell as follows:

```
"this is a string" -file "my.ps1"
```

It is taking the first as a string, the `-file` as the `-f` format flag and saying it doesn't have a value expression on the right for the format substitution.

Try like this:

<strike>& "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"</strike>

(as Keith notes, this will not work as this is run from a bat file than Powershell.)

Or just:

```
powershell.exe -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"
```

Comment: so the problem is on "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"?

Comment: @tugberk - It is being treated as a string. See my updated answer giving suggestions for you to try.

Comment: I can get this to work until I have parameters with spaces. How would I call this with parameters with spaces?

Answer (score 17):

Visual Studio writes the post-build event script to a .BAT file and executes that using cmd.exe.  So using `& "<path-to-powershell>"` won't work.  Just execute:

```
Powershell.exe -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"
```

And if you think you're likely to run into execution policy issues on other machines that build the solution, consider going this route:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"
```

Comment: My bad, forgot about bat and also that OP had tried it in Powershell console. So should the file part be `$($SolutionDir)` ( I changed it from OP's initial one thinking it was PS ), but I suppose VS / MSBuild would need it in a different way? `$(SolutionDir)`?

Comment: No biggie. Yeah, it should be `$(SolutionDir)`. That's how you reference a property in MSBuild. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: according to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx  
"File must be the last parameter in the command"
so it should be:  
Powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "$(SolutionDir)tools\nuget_pack.ps1"  
BTW. thanks to this you can add params to ps1

Answer (score 1):

Before calling power-shell script from visual studio, set the ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted from power-shell window like this...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser;
ExecutionPolicy: unrestricted;
```

the call power-shell script in the following manner...

```
powershell.exe $(SolutionDir)Setup.ps1 -SolutionDir $(SolutionDir) -ProjectPath $(ProjectPath)
```

[image]

then in the script, you can always read the parameter like this...

```
param([string]$SolutionDir,
     [string]$ProjectPath);
#Write-Host ($SolutionDir +" Call this script with following aruments");
#Write-Host ($ProjectPath +" Call this script with following aruments");
```